# Issue with looping the nc open function

Tags: r, netcdf

I am trying to loop the

```
ncin_old<-nc_open("filename", write=TRUE, readunlim=TRUE, verbose=FALSE, 
           auto_GMT=TRUE, suppress_dimvals=FALSE )
```

function like this

```
library(ncdf.tools)
library(ncdf4)
library(ncdf4.helpers)
library(RNetCDF)
library(abind)
setwd("D:/Rwork/Project")   # set working folder

# This is the directory where the file for analysing are
dir("D:/Rwork/Project/MASTER_FILES")-> xlab 
filelist <- paste("MASTER_FILES/", dir("MASTER_FILES"), sep="") 

N <- length(filelist)     # Loop over the individual files
for(j in 1:N) { 
  ncin_old <- nc_open("filelist[j]", write=TRUE, readunlim=TRUE, verbose=FALSE, 
           auto_GMT=TRUE, suppress_dimvals=FALSE )
}
```

But I get this error

> Error in nc_open("filelist[j]", write = TRUE, readunlim = TRUE,
>   verbose = FALSE,  :    Error in nc_open trying to open file
>   filelist[j]

If I drop everything after `filelist[j]` the lat file in the loop opens
but the `nc_open(x, write)` does not seem to like being looped.

Comment: Thank you Marco for the edit. That must better, much clearer

Comment: are you calling `close.ncdf()` at the end of your loop?

Comment: I have nc_close() at the end. Is that wrong ?

Comment: No, I think thats the right thing to do

Comment: Now I am getting the following Error message :-    "Error, passed variable has a dim that is NOT of class ncdim4!"

Comment: any way you could publicly post these ncdf files?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed some issues of your code as below. I think now it is correct.

```
library(ncdf4)
# set the folder with the files
setwd("D:/Rwork/Project/MASTER_FILES")

# you need the files path, not the directory path
# list only the files with the .nc extension
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "\\.nc$")

# Loop over the individual files
# The filelist cannot be between quotation marks as in your code
N <- length(filelist)
for(j in 1:N) { 
  ncin_old <- nc_open(filelist[j], write=TRUE, readunlim=TRUE, verbose=FALSE, 
           auto_GMT=TRUE, suppress_dimvals=FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used lapply:

```
library(ncdf4)
# set the folder that contains all the files
setwd("C:/...")

# create a list with the files with the .nc extension
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "*.nc")
filelist # It contains all the files .nc

# To open all files: Loop over the individual files
for (i in 1:length(filelist)) { 
     all_nc_files <- lapply(filelist, nc_open)
}
```

Running that, I obtain "all_nc_files", which contains all .nc files opened and now I can work with them.
Hope it works!